# Not able to setattr using class.__setattr__(key,value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, getattr, setattr

I have my code like this one:

```
class __Metadata(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super().__init__(name, bases, dict)
        
   
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
        return

class SimpleData(metaclass=__Metadata):
    pass


class Data1(SimpleData):
    BOOK = "Book1"
    SPORT = "Football"
    OTHER = "Other"
```

when i try this one:

```
Data1.__setattr__("FILM", "Avengers")
```

im getting this error:

```
TypeError:  expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

how can i fix this so when i use: `Data1.__getattribute__("FILM")` i get Avengers

Comment: Why have you name-mangled the abstract class?

Comment: Why are you using a custom metaclass at all?

Comment: Why are you bothering to define methods that are just passthrus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're sharing the full code, but these functions do not relate to each other at all, the `setattr` question has been asked so many times before..

You don't need a custom meta class, or `SimpleData` (while I have no idea what this could do):

```
class Data1(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        super().__setattr__('attr', dict())
        self.attr = attr

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.attr:
            return self.attr[name]
        else:
            return 0

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.attr:
            self.attr[key] = value
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)

       # return is irrelevant

d = Data1({"book": "Book1"})
print(d.book)
# Book1
```

Comment: You don't need the passthru `__init__` on the metaclass either